# Hibernate criteria order by a linking table column

Tags: hql, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-entitymanager

I have membership and person tables that are linked with manyToMany relationship via a person_membership table. The person_membership table include person_id, membership_id and a sequence_number. The Membership entity has the below code to link to the person table.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "person_membership", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "membership_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }
)
public Set<Person> getPersons() {
    return this.persons;
}
```

Retrieving memberships is done via criteria using the below code:

```
Session session = getSession();
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Membership.class, "membership");
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("membershipNumber", membershipNumber));

        return (Membership) c.uniqueResult();
```

What I want to do is sorting the result by person_membership.sequence_number. How can I do that using a criteria or may be there is another way to do it?

I am after a nice, clean and not complicated way if possible :)

Comment: If you apply uniqueResult, you'll get one row, so what do you want order?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the persons while fetching, mention the "sequenceNumber" column using JPA @OrderBy annotation

```
@OrderBy("sequenceNumber")
public Set<Person> getPersons() {
```

If you want to order all Memberships by person_membership.sequence_number and then return the first or distinct one in the result as below.

HQL

```
select distinct m 
from Membership m 
join m.persons p 
order by p.sequenceNumber;
```

Criteria

```
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Membership.class, "membership");
    c.createCriteria("membership.persons", "person");
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("membershipNumber", membershipNumber));
    c.addOrder(Order.asc("person.sequenceNumber"))
    c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)

    return (Membership) c.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The above throws property not found exception as sequence_number belongs to the person_membership table which I don't have an entity for (not required by Hibernet to set ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: if there is no mapping then i guess only way is to retrieve by native SQL.

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess too but thought I ask first :)